# Sort sunspot solr dynamic fields on datatable

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Saved custom field data in below foremat inside solr.

dynamic_string :custom, stored: true do
custom_fields.inject({}) do |hash, custom_field|
hash.merge((custom_field.key) => custom_field.value)
end
end

While sort dynamiclly append _fs at last
sort[0] = "label"
sort[1] = desc

String become as

sort: "custom:label_fs asc"

How to fix this for dynamic field